# How do I install a tarball with home-manager?

Tags: nixos, nix

I’m really new to nix so a detailed explanation of the solution would be appreciated.

I’m trying to add [rnix-lsp](https://github.com/nix-community/rnix-lsp) to my home config. The instructions on the github page simply state to run a nix-env command on a url to a tarball which I’m not sure what to do with.

I know about `fetchTarball`, but I can’t figure out how to use it in a way that works with `home.packages`. I’ve tried something like this:

```
home.packages = [
    (import (fetchTarball “https://github.com/nix-community/rnix-lsp/archive/master.tar.gz”) {}; ).defaultNix
];
```

But then I get an error about trying to call a set. Is there any way to do what I want to do?

The error specifically:

```
error: attempt to call something which is not a function but a set, at /home/izzylan/.config/nixpkgs/home.nix:33:9
```

Comment: https://releases.nixos.org/nix-dev/2015-March/016435.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the answer to this myself by diving into the source code:

```
import (fetchTarball “https://github.com/nix-community/rnix-lsp/archive/master.tar.gz”)
```

### Why this works

We can see in [home-environment.nix](https://github.com/nix-community/home-manager/blob/c2c26120d7e76b2ab9a2f6584c8d6223fbd1123a/modules/home-environment.nix#L289) that home-manager expects that `home.packages` expects a type that's a list of `types.package`. This is defined in the nixpkgs module, so we can check `types.nix` to see how nix determines what is a "package". We can then find the [definition for the package type](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/9839cda8dc0eae5fd2af4ffc970c95ebaa59b92c/lib/types.nix#L331) and see that a package is either a derivation or a string containing a store path.

rnix-lsp is already a nix project and exports itself as a derivation in default.nix.<sup>1</sup> Therefore, all we need to is download it as a tarball, and import it into our config. `home-manager` will then happily take the derivation, build it, and install it like any other package.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically it's defined as a [flake](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Flakes) in `flake.nix` and `default.nix` uses flake-compat to export it as a derivation.